# SQL Server database doesn't save the new queries until the application is closed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a problem with saving queries into my Local DB in the current session. However, the database got updated when I close the app.

**Scenario**: I have a login Window and Register Window, when user register I have queries to save his/her info into DB but after closing the whole application, it should save it in the same session without needing to close the app.

I'm using this code for registration window:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox.Text.Length >= 4 && textBox1.Password.Length >= 4)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source"))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText =
                 "Select Count(*) From Results Where PlayerName = @playerName";
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters?.Add("@playerName", textBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters?.Add("@Password", textBox1.Password);

            var count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (count == 0)
            {
               cmd.CommandText =
                  "INSERT INTO LoginInfo (PlayerName, Password) Values (@playerName , @Password)";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               conn.Close();
               Close();
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Content = "The UserName is already registerd!";
            }
         }
     }
     else
     {
        label3.Content =
                "Please Enter Valid information User Name +" +
                "and Password should be more than 4 Digits";
     }
}
```

**Edit:** I used `@displayName`, suggestion and I saw that actually it updated because when I'm writing same info it gives that user already registered.
Probably there is a mistake with `Linq to SQL` in `login window` here is my login window code:

```
 private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var userName = from t in db.LoginInfos
            select new
            {
                t.Id,
                t.PlayerName,
                t.Password
            };

        foreach (var variable in userName)
        {
            if (UserName.Text == variable.PlayerName && text_Password.Password == variable.Password)
            {
                var openChoiceGame = new ChoiceGame(UserName.Text);
                textBlock.Text = "The login information are correct ";
                openChoiceGame.Show();

                using (
                    var conn =
                        new SqlConnection(
                            @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Saif-DevEnv\Source\Workspaces\QuizClashGame\GameQuizClash\Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
                    )
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) From Results Where PlayerName = @playerName";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerName", UserName.Text);
                    conn.Open();

                    var count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        // It means it does not exist.
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Results(PlayerName) VALUES (@playerName)";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                    var player = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Saif-DevEnv\Desktop\SoundRes\switch32.wav");
                    player.Play();
                }

                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                textBlock.Text = "The login information are not correct ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Are there any errors with Login window code?

Comment: Have you tried putting your `conn.Close();` outside of the conditional `if` statement?

Comment: Yes I tried that one it doesn't change any thing.

Comment: Why are calling conn.Close() inside a using block? Connection gets closed and disposed at the end of the using block. On another note, what's with the Close() calling? If this call closes your app move it outside the using block.

Comment: 'conn.Close()' I know it's mean nth here but I used just to try that could work. and for ur suggestion I have tried and if doesn't work as well.

Comment: Do `int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and tell what's the return value that you are getting?

Comment: That implies the player has been added and therefore the value is available to use. You can verify that (without closing the app) by trying to add the same player again and it won't let you add.

Comment: You are right that what should happen, but in my case that in run time when I'm going back to Login it says that is not in DB. As well as in run time the database doesn't changed.

Comment: Are you by any chance initiating a transaction (BeginTransaction) anywhere before that command execution, cause if you do you won't see any changes in the DB until you call transaction.Commit(), which is called on app close by default so any changes get flushed into the DB.

Comment: @Jimi , No I didn't but maybe the problem it happeaning because the linq to Sql in Login window I didn't use a good way.

Comment: @displayName  maybe u can see the code of login window, Do u think there is a problem with Linq to Sql ?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the problem is there. You are using LINQ to SQL and also modifying the SQL data. The results would be unexpected. Materialize your `userName` list by calling a .ToList() on it first. Then, after adding the new user, make a fresh LINQ to SQL and the user will appear in the new `userName` list.

Comment: And for userid/password validation, the best approach is to create a Stored Procedure in the database and pass the values to it for deciding whether to allow a login or not. Create a method that calls that SProc and returns a boolean whether the login info is correct or not.

Comment: well it seams a solution I will try it out, Thanks!

Comment: @displayName see my answer below for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `Linq To Sql` part.
However,the solution for it was I have added the source of data into `DataContext(@DataSource)` or in my code is `DataClasses1DataContext(@DataSource);`and also use  `Refresh` Method `db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,_db.LoginInfos);`

Answer (score 0):

**First thought:** I see that you are ExecutingScalar() on `Results` while ExecutingNonQuery() on `LoginInfo` i.e. on two different tables. Is that the issue?

**Second thought:** You can change the way you are testing for inserting into `LoginInfo`. Do it this way rather -

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == -1)
{
    label3.Content = "The UserName is already registerd!";
}
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar* is used for `Select` and ExecuteNonQuery** for `Insert` and `Update`. There is nothing wrong in that.
*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx
**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you ,It was mistake but it change nth because the 'Results' has the same player names in 'LoginInfo'. but it change nth same main problem

Comment: And also as same as Jimi said, there is no problem with using ExecuteScalar for Select to gives me back if data has this name before.

Comment: @SaifAlradhi: I pointed that out because I thought that the problem was in testing wrong table.

Comment: Well, with ur answer I saw it save it correctly! because when I register it again I see it already register so that's led me to there is an missing command in Linq To SQL ORM.

Comment: I will try to play around with linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for the async keyword.  It should work fine after you remove that.

Comment: You are right. There is no need for the `async` if `await` is not used.

Comment: well, i'm using await but to make the code clear and short. and actually it has no effect on this issue.

Comment: If there's more code then you should post it.  If you are using await then something you called with it may not be returning until after the program closes causing the sql commands to not run till then

Comment: @ScottMacMaster well, await it just been used to for delay to show some Gif animation any way this problem is happening in other classes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would say the problem its far from Async, it's related with one from two.
Sql Query or Linq to Sql ORM